# What is the mathematical theory behind this linear combination inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I see an interesting formula in a paper today. The author  states this:

Assume that $\sum_{m=1}^M w_m= 1,\  \text{for} \;\;w_m \geq 0$, and $X = \sum_{m=1}^M w_m x_m,  \forall x_m \in \mathbb{R}$.

So $\underset{1\leq m\leq M}{\min} x_m \leq X\leq \underset{1\leq m\leq M}{\max} x_m$.

This inequality is intuitive, but I could not rigorously prove its truth. I want to understand the theorem behind this inequality, could anyone tell me? Thanks in advance!

P.S. Since I do not know what this problem is belong to, please anyone could help me improve the tags :)

(Edit: $w_m \in \mathbb{R} $ -> $w_m \geq 0$ )

Comment: I think you don't mean "$\forall w_m \in \mathbb{R}$". I think you mean "where each $w_m \in \mathbb{R}$".

Comment: @PatrickStevens Yep, the latter one is what I want to express. But what is the *exact* difference between these two expressions?

Comment: I don't really know how to express "for all $w_m \in \mathbb{R}$" in any other way. It means "whenever $w_m \in \mathbb{R}$". You mean "for each fixed $\{w_1, w_2, \dots, w_m\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$"

Comment: @PatrickStevens I got you! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the claim is not true. A counterexample is:

- $w_1 = -1$
- $w_2=2$.
- $x_1=200$
- $x_2=100$

In this case, $X=-1\cdot 200 + 2\cdot 100 = -200 + 200 = 0$, however while $\max_{1\leq m\leq 2} x_m=200$ and $\min_{1\leq m\leq 2} x_m=100$. Clearly, the inequalities $100 \leq 0 \leq 200$ do not hold in this case.

---

However, the claim is true if $w_m\geq 0$ for all $m$. Then, you can prove the inequalities like so:

$$X = \sum_{m=1}^M w_m x_m \leq \sum_{m=1}^M w_m \max_{1\leq m \leq M}{x_m} = \max_{1\leq m \leq M}{x_m}\cdot \sum_{m=1}^M w_m =\max_{1\leq m \leq M}{x_m}\cdot 1 = \max_{1\leq m \leq M}{x_m} $$

and similarly for the other inequality.

The trick here is that, for every $m$, you know that $$x_m\leq \max_{1\leq m\leq M} x_m$$

and you can multiply this inequality by $w_m$ (**only if you know that $w_m\geq 0$!!!**) to get

$$w_m x_m\leq w_m\cdot \max_{1\leq m\leq M} x_m$$

Comment: Oh, Sorry! $w_m  \ \text{is } \geq 0$ in that paper. It is my mistake

Comment: @standerQiu Well, my answer also explains (hopefully) why the requirement $w_m\geq 0$ is actually required.

Comment: Thanks your answer! It is just a simple equality that I should prove myself . lol

Comment: You have exactly explained, thank you!